# Solving equation ${x^4} + a{x^3} + b{x^2} + ax + 1 = 0$

Tags: polynomials

The equation ${x^4} + a{x^3} + b{x^2} + ax + 1 = 0$ has at least one real root and if the minimum value of $E(a,b)=a^2+b^2$ can be expressed as $\frac{p}{q}$ whwre $H.C.F(p,q)=1$, then the value of $p^2+q^2=$______

Let ${x^4} + a{x^3} + b{x^2} + ax + 1 = \left( {x - \alpha } \right)\left( {x - \beta } \right)\left( {x - \gamma } \right)\left( {x - \lambda } \right)$

Let us assume that $a,b $ are real

Let $\alpha  + \beta  + \gamma  + \lambda  =  - a\& \alpha \beta  + \beta \gamma  + \gamma \lambda  + \alpha \gamma  + \alpha \lambda  + \beta \lambda  = b$ and also $\alpha \beta \gamma  + \alpha \beta \lambda  + \alpha \gamma \lambda  + \beta \gamma \lambda  =  - a\& \alpha \beta \gamma \lambda  = 1$

The only posibility is either you have all imaginary roots that is neglected hence

Case (1) is that you have two real roots and tw imaginary roots

Case (2) is that you have all real roots

I am not able to proceed with the above two cases

Comment: Hint: it is a [palindromic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Palindromic_and_antipalindromic_polynomials), so it is a quadratic in  $\,z=x + \frac{1}{x}\,$.

Comment: Well, “it” is $x^2$ times a quadratic polynomial in $z,$ if by “it” we mean the polynomial. @dxiv

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In general, yes, but in this case $x=0$ is known to *not* be a root, so the factor $x^2$ can be safely dropped without altering the solution set, which leaves just the quadratic in $z$.

Comment: @dvix You are misreading my comment. Try writing that polynomial as a quadratic in $x+1/x.$ You can’t.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ${x^4} + a{x^3} + b{x^2} + ax + 1 = 0 \iff z^2 + a z + b - 2 =0$ where $z=x+\frac{1}{x}$. What I meant is the equation, not the polynomial. Guess it's too late to edit the comment now to clarify.

Comment: To the OP: If you will pardon my saying so, much of the confusion in the back and forth comments so far are the result of your ignoring the MathSE protocol represented by [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) and not including pertinent facts directly in your posting.  What I am specifically focusing on is the following pertinent details: [1] What is your Math background/education ? [2] What is the exact source of the problem? ...see next comment

Comment: [3] As discussed in the linked article, what *tools* that are part of the recent training that you have received might plausibly be relevant? -- Nailing down these topics will help with what I regard to be a critical question: What is the intent of the problem composer as to the educational value of the question and the appropriate strategy in deriving a solution?  This **meta-cheating** question, while probably not appropriate for graduate level Math, should generally be appropriate for undergraduate Math.